# apache not working httpd lightsail instance lamp bitnami

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, http, ssl, https

When I restart my instance in lightsail I get the "apache server not running". When I run the command

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart
```

I get this error:

```
Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : apache not running
/opt/bitnami/php/scripts/ctl.sh : php-fpm stopped
/opt/bitnami/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh : mysql stopped
/opt/bitnami/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh : mysql  started at port 3306
/opt/bitnami/php/scripts/ctl.sh : php-fpm started
Syntax OK
(98)Address already in use: AH00073: make_sock: unable to listen for connections on address
[::]:443
(98)Address already in use: AH00073: make_sock: unable to listen for connections on address 0.0.0.0:443
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd could not be started
```

I' m blocked, I don't know what can I do; all websites are down and I get the error `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` when I want to redirect to all my websites.

Comment: Apache did not start, and that's why you get ssl errors or cannot connect at all. Why didn't Apache start? It says there in the error message: it cannot listen for connections on port 443 (https). That can mean that either it doesn't have permissions (unlikely since you used `sudo`) or something else is already using that port. Stop that other service and Apache should start.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'`

tcp6 0 0 :::80 :::* LISTEN 1584/httpd

`sudo kill -9 1584`

`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`

Repeat the command until you kill all conflicting processes